# Adding social integration to my website

Tags: gwt, social-networking

I have a GWT web-app to which I would like to add some social features. I am using Google maps and basically there are several markers on the map. When a user clicks on a marker a new DialogBox is opened. Each marker has a unique ID associated to it. In the dialog box the user has the option to start a discussion using comments. I tried using Disqus and Google+ comments, but they need a unique page URL for each comment box, i.e for each marker, I would have to create a new page, which is not possible as the markers increase as the users drop them on the map. Facebook comments does serve my purpose as it checks for the validity of the URL only upto .appspot.com/, so I put my ID after the /, and even though such a page does not exist, the comment box works. But the Facebook comment box does not render everytime.

At this point, I am open to solutions that might force me to work from scratch.

To sum it all up. I have a unique ID, a dialog box and I want to add commenting, in a way that does not require me to create unique pages for each ID.

Also, is it possible to make GWT create pages on the fly ?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide unique url to each marker, you just have to use history tokens. You can read more about GWT's history mechanism here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html